# Integrate function in a clockwise sense around a circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Integrate $f(z)=(z-z_0)^m$, where $m$ is an integer and $z_0$ is a constant, in a clockwise sense around the circle C of radius p with center at $z_0$

The solution goes like :

$(z-z_0)^m = p^m e^{im\theta}$, $dz=ipe^{id\theta}d\theta$

$\int_C (z-z_0)^m dz=\int_0^{2\pi} p^me^{im\theta}d\theta$

$=2\pi i ;(m=-1)$

$=0 ;(m\ne-1)$

My question is how did $(z-z_0)^m=p^me^{im\theta}$ and how to determine that $-1$ is the only point where the answer is not equal to $0$.

Comment: What they forgot to write is $z = z_0 + pe^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 1):

For the first question note that the path is $z_0+pe^{i\theta} $ and not $pe^{i\theta}$.

If $m \neq -1$ we can write $(z-z_0)^{m}$ as the derivative of $\frac {(z-z_0)^{m+1}} {m+1}$ and the integral of any derivative over a closed contour is always $0$. Note that this does not work when $m=-1$. For this case you have to evaluate the integral directly from the definition.